# Webdesite taking too long to load all of a sudden

Tags: joomla-2.5

Recently my client told me all of a sudden his website started loading slowly. When I checked out with pingdom tools, I realized it is taking exactly 60 seconds to load. Changed the template to another one, still the same thing, and disabled all modules, cleared cache, and still the same thing. THe only thing I hven't done yet was to disable all plugins, because he's got too many plugins, anyway, I believe it is not the plugins, as the page load is happening only in the homepage.

Here http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/ePSOQN/http://www.grupoagilisa.com.br

http://www.grupoagilisa.com.br

I'm working on it right now.

EDIT: My bad, the problem also happens in the other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing I can recommend doing is:

1. Ask your client if they have touched any of the Joomla settings or installed any 3rd party extensions. I say this as I know clients can be a pain in the backside sometimes and like to experiment with things they have no experience with.
2. Take a backup of the website using either [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html) or manually downloading a zip of the site and database. Install the backup on a localhost environment such as [Wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en) and test the speed there. If the site is still slow, then try uninstalling each 3rd party extension 1 by 1. If the site loads at a normal speed, then it will most likely be a hosting related issue.

Hope this helps

Comment: But it was all of sudden, he haven't done anything. His website was there fully working, then one day it started to load slow.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, take a backup of the site and test

Comment: Other thing, don't you think it's funny that it takes exactly 60 seconds to load?

Comment: I only took me 10 seconds to load. When loading, I saw that it was trying to connect to `www.site4fast.com`. So it's possible that an extension on there is trying to pull external data or quite possibly the site has been hacked. Please oh please say you are running the latest version of Joomla

Comment: site 4 fast!!! Sir, you're a genious!

Comment: Great, did you figure out what was trying to get data from there?

Comment: site4fast is a support chat tool, looks like site4fast website doesn't exist anymore, but the script must still be installed in Joomla, I have to find out where now.

Comment: Check your Module Manager, Plugin Manager and Component list. Shouldn't be too hard to find

Comment: It indeed was the module. Thank you mister Lodder, I wouldn't have made it today if it hadn't been for you. I would have taken a whole lot longer.

Comment: @Sora - You're more than welcome ;)

Comment: *the Chat module.<br>
:)